# Your app utilizes a version of Vitamio, a multimedia library used for playing various types of media files, containing a security vulnerability

Tags: android-security, vitamio

I developed an app that'll stream a rtmp video. Before I used VitamioBundle-master. I upload my app in play store it shows some warning message for upgrading my app that has to use vitamio latest version. I download it from the link shown in that alert message. Now I develop the app using vitamio 5.0.2 downloaded from the link https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/. Once I upload the app play store shows the same alert message

> Security alert
>   Your app utilizes a version of Vitamio, a multimedia library used for playing various types of media files, containing a security vulnerability.
>
> Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK. Beginning 14 March 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates that use pre-5.0 versions of Vitamio.
>
> The vulnerability was addressed in Vitamio v5.0. The latest versions of Vitamio can be downloaded on the Vitamio website. You can confirm your Vitamio version by checking if the SDK includes libs/armeabi-v7a/libvinit.so or libs/armeabi/libvinit.so. If either file is present, the SDK needs to be upgraded. For help upgrading, see the Vitamio support documentation. If you’re using a 3rd party library that bundles Vitamio, please notify the 3rd party and work with them to address this.
>
> To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version to the Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app hasn’t been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning.
>   The vulnerability is due to the Vitamio SDK containing world-writable code. For more information about the vulnerability, please see this NowSecure blog post. For other technical questions, you can post to Stack Overflow and use the tags “android-security” and “vitamio.”
>
> While these specific issues may not affect every app that uses Vitamio, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Apps with vulnerabilities that expose users to risk of compromise may be considered in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
>
> Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies. If you feel we have sent this warning in error, contact our policy support team through the Google Play Developer Help Center.

I gone through several solutions mentioned in different tutorial but not yet get a clear idea. Can anyone tell me the step by step procedure for updating my vitamio sdk version, or else is there any other lib for streaming rtmp video in my Android app?

Comment: Have you waited five hours after updating? It's mentioned in the fourth paragraph.

Comment: yes,still now it shows the same alert message.is there any other option for vitamio security issue

Comment: @uma How you have implemented vitamio 5.0.2. It example is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Vitamio 5.0.2 added back the old libvinit.so file, so it gets flagged as an old version of Vitamio. You can just delete libvinit.so and it should work.

Comment: hi,actually the app working fine with vitamio 5.0.2,but the problem i faced is the app crashes on the kitkat and older version.is vitamio only supported by lollipop and higher version.is there any other solution for this issue.